# grab last four digits approach after deleting non digits using regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm getting the URL(`http://localhost:8080/CompanyServices/api/creators/2173`) shown below from a HTTP Response header and I want to get the `id` after the `creators` which is `2173`.

So, I deleted all non digits as shown below and got the following result : `80802173`. 
Is it a good approach to get the last 4 digits from the above set of digits?

One thing is that, this part `localhost:8080` could change depending upon the server I deploy my application so I'm wondering if I should just grab something after `creators/` ? If yes, then what is the best way to go about it?

```
public class GetLastFourIDs {


    public static void main(String args[]){  
        String str = "http://localhost:8080/CompanyServices/api/creators/2173";
        String replaceString=str.replaceAll("\\D+","");
        System.out.println(replaceString);  
        } 

}
```

Comment: Use: `(?<=creators/)\d+`

Comment: Use `String id = str.replaceFirst("^.*?(\\d+)$", "$1");`

Comment: @Andreas Could you explain `String id = str.replaceFirst("^.*?(\\d+)$", "$1");` ? This worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex API e.g.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "http://localhost:8080/CompanyServices/api/creators/2173";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(creators/\\d+)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        int value = 0;
        if (matcher.find()) {
            // Get e.g. `creators/2173` and split it on `/` then parse the second value to int
            value = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group().split("/")[1]);
        }
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2173
```

**Non-regex solution:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "http://localhost:8080/CompanyServices/api/creators/2173";
        int index = str.indexOf("creators/");
        int value = 0;
        if (index != -1) {
            value = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(index + "creators/".length()));
        }
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2173
```

**[Update]**

Incorporating [comment by Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62031798/grab-last-four-digits-approach-after-deleting-non-digits-using-regex/62031936#comment109714078_62031936) as follows:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "http://localhost:8080/CompanyServices/api/creators/2173";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("creators/(\\d+)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        int value = 0;
        if (matcher.find()) {
            value = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
        }
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2173
```

Comment: Change `"(creators/\\d+)"` to `"creators/(\\d+)"` so you don't have to do that unnecessary `split("/")`